# Access token is seen on response tab

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am implementing a Web API with angularjs. I can run it without any hassle and get what I want the only thing is, I am able to see my "access_token" in the "Response" tab of my "Network" tab. Although it is encrypted, I am able to see it. My question is:
1. Is that safe? 
2. How do I hide it if it is not a good practice?
3. When I copy this "access_token" and place it in a "Postman" application, I can actually get authenticated. How do I go about it, to avoid that?

**Get token from server**

```
myApp.factory('accountService', [
    '$http', '$q', 'serviceBasePath', 'userService', function($http, $q, serviceBasePath, userService) {
        var fac = {};
        fac.login = function(user) {
            var obj = { 'username': user.username, 'password': user.password, 'grant_type': 'password' };
            Object.toparams = function ObjectsToParams(obj) {
                var p = [];
                for (var key in obj) {
                    p.push(key + '=' + encodeURIComponent(obj[key]));
                }
                return p.join('&');
            }

            var defer = $q.defer();
            $http({
                method: 'post',
                url: serviceBasePath + "/token",
                data: Object.toparams(obj),
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).then(function(response) {
                userService.SetCurrentUser(response.data);
                defer.resolve(response.data);
            }, function(error) {
                defer.reject(error.data);
            });
            return defer.promise;
        }
    fac.logout = function() {
        userService.CurrentUser = null;
        userService.SetCurrentUser(userService.CurrentUser);
    }
    return fac;
}
]);
```

**Set and Get the token**

```
myApp.factory('userService', function () {
    var fac = {};
    fac.CurrentUser = null;
    fac.SetCurrentUser = function (user) {
        fac.CurrentUser = user;
        sessionStorage.user = angular.toJson(user);
    }

    fac.GetCurrentUser = function () {
        fac.CurrentUser = angular.fromJson(sessionStorage.user);
        return fac.CurrentUser;
    }
    return fac;
});
```

Comment: have a look https://rnd.feide.no/2012/04/19/best-practice-for-dealing-with-oauth-2-0-token-expiration-at-the-consumer/

Comment: Thanks for the link but I think it doesn't address my questions. The only information I actually got from it is to set the time of validity of access tokens which I actually had done by setting it to 1 day (not in my codes though, but I did set it.)

Comment: what kind of a token is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For security do the following:

Make sure the access token cookie is a secure cookie.

Make sure the access token cookie is an HTTPS only cookie.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Cookies#Secure_and_HttpOnly_cookies

Also your server prob has a secret key to decode the cookie. Make sure you keep it private (don't put it on a public repo).

Make sure you understand the difference between authorisation (401 if not authorised) and authentication (403 if not authenticated). The basic difference here is that failure to authorise will not let you in. Whereas authentication will only give certain users access to certain server endpoints.

e.g. A user in group1 may be able to GET data but not POST new data. They would get a 403 if they tried to POST. A user in group2 can POST to their hearts content.

Comment: What do you mean by "the access token cookie is a secure cookie"? The access_token is actually encrypted but the problem is; somebody can just open the developer tab and copy the access_token, open up postman, paste it in the headers then they will be authenticated. I am using the 401 and 403 already. I just want to hide the "access_token" so they cannot use it to copy and paste to postman or some other application just like that.

Comment: it is no problem that they can copy paste it - they are an authorised user given that they have a valid access token - just make sure you expire it every so often - a secure cookie means JavaScript cant access it such that a script running on your page cannot read it, it can only be sent in server requests and is set by the server using the Set-Cookie response header

Comment: But what about this scenario: "legit_user" logs in, do valid stuff that they are authorized to do like search, insert, update, & delete, closes the browser without logging off, then leaves his desk for some reason. "Mr_X" opens the browser, presses "f12", copies the "access_token", use postman, then use the access rights of "legit_user"?

Comment: well if you are really worried you encode the ip they are accessing from inside the access token so if mr x tries to access from another ip it will fail - you would need to decode and verify the ip server side - overkill imo

Comment: Oh I see. Last thing.. Will my "access_token" here work on another pc?

Comment: Ouch. I need to figure out a way to make this access tomennit reusable when simebody copies and paste it on another computer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to avoid that. Similarly you can take your authentication cookie on any website and use Postman to make calls to the website as your user.

If you send the token to the browser, the user can get it.

You need to make sure that you check on your server-side if the user has permissions to do the thing they are trying to do. Then it does not matter if a user takes the token and makes calls manually as the only things they can do are things they would be able to do normally through the app anyway.

Comment: Oh! So basically all I can do is just to use "least privilege" since there is no way to hide the "access_token".